# System can't find paths when building .sln with Bamboo

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bamboo

I'm trying to build a project of our Visual Studio 2010 solution with the Visual Studio task which comes with Bamboo. but once the build starts it fails to find the required files (see logfile below).

When I try to build the project in the command line, it works fine.
When I try to do this exact thing with Bamboo's 'Command'-task, however, I get the same errors that I get with the Visual Studio task.

So I gather my files are checked out just fine and the problem is with Bamboo.
Seeing how the problem only occurs when moc'ing, uic'ing or rcc'ing I think it might be a Qt-related problem. All executables (moc.exe, uic.exe...) are in my PATH though, so I don't see how they are not found.

---

Here's the logfile of the failed build:
It's in german, so you should know that 'Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.' means that the system can't find the specified path.

```
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Build TEST-TEST01-BUILD-83 started building on            agent Default Agent
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Build working directory is C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-BUILD
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Executing build TEST-TEST01-BUILD-83
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Running pre-build action: Build Number Stamper
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Running pre-build action: Clover Grails PreBuild   Action
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Running pre-build action: Repository Isolation Enabler Action
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Running pre-build action: Maven Settings Prebuild     Action
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Starting task 'Build Project with IDE' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugin.dotnet:devenv'
command 01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Beginning to execute external process for build 'TestProject - TestPlan_01 - Build Project'\n ... running command line: \nC:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\DotNetSupport\devenvrunner.bat C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-BUILD c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 x86 C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-JOB1\monalysis\MonAlysis\MonAlysis.sln /build Debug /project Core\n ... in: C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-BUILD\n
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   10.0" 
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-BUILD>call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:32    Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:35    
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:35    Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.30319.1.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:35    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:35    1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: Core, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>Der Buildvorgang wurde am 01.03.2013 13:47:36 gestartet.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>InitializeBuildStatus:
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>  Aktualisieren des Timestamps von "C:\Users\Fujitsu\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TEST-TEST01-JOB1\monalysis\MonAlysis\Core\GeneratedFiles\Debug\Core.unsuccessfulbuild".
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>CustomBuild:
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>  Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:36    1>  Uic'ing Source\About.ui...

... (The same error happens for all the files, but only when Uic'ing, Moc'ing or Rcc'ing)

build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 3 beendet.
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    1>
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    1>Fehler beim Erstellen
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    1>
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    1>Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:00.57
build   01-Mrz-2013 13:47:37    ========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, Fehler bei 1, 0 aktuell, 0 ?bersprungen ==========
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Failing task since return code was 1 while expected 0
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Finished task 'Build Project with IDE'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running post build plugin 'Cleanup Build Processor'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Finalising the build...
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Stopping timer.
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Build TEST-TEST01-BUILD-83 completed.
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    All post build plugins have finished
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Generating build results summary...
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Saving build results to disk...
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Indexing build results...
simple  01-Mrz-2013 13:47:39    Finished building TEST-TEST01-BUILD-83.
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The problem wasn't that the files couldn't be found, but that Bamboo can't find the moc.exe, uic.exe and rcc.exe. They are in the PATH, which is good enough for building it from the command line. Bamboo however doesn't seem to use PATH.

So the best I can do is a workaround which is simply moc'ing, uic'ing and rcc'ing manually via batch files.

The general problem however still remains, which could just as well be the cause for [my other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268612/fatal-error-lnk1104-cant-open-lnkn-tmp).
So please post any ideas you might have on how to tell Bamboo where it finds the moc/uic/rcc.exe.

Comment: I recommend you to answer your own question. Put there the "UPDATE" from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your task config you can set the Environment Variables Bamboo should be using

eg:

```
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64"
```

Heres what I did in my build bat file (see comment below)

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\bin\qmake.exe  C:\bhome\xml-data\build-dir\...\project.pro  -r  -spec  win32-msvc2012  "CONFIG+=debug"  "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"  "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that already, but to no avail. It just seems to be a very bad idea to use Bamboo for Qt-projects (at the moment).

Comment: The other thing you can try is using a batch file to do your build.  That's what I ended up doing with my bamboo project.  This is what my code looks like.  The important thing is the middle line, calling the vs file that adds the paths and everything. (edited answer to properly format code)

Comment: That's basically what I did too (see my update in the original question). Yours looks better though, so I'll probably try that instead.